# deep copy and dynamic cast unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, unique-ptr, deep-copy

Suppose I have a class like the following:

```
class A { virtual ~A(); ... }
class B : public A { ... }
class C : public A { ... }
```

I also have a vector of unique_ptr which is declared this way:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec;
```

Assume vec is populated with unique_ptr to objects of derived class. What should I do if I want a deep copy of any of the vector elements, either b or c, and let a base class unique_ptr pointing to it? Originally I was doing things like

```
std::unique_ptr<A> tmp = std::make_unique<A>(*b);
```

I don't think this is correct.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with `unique_ptr`. `A *tmp = new A(*b);` would be no more correct.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I want to use unique_ptr as I don't want to use raw pointers directly.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But the reason why what you posted is incorrect has *nothing* to do with the fact that you're using `unique_ptr`s. It's not a problem with `unique_ptr` or `make_unique` or anything like that.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas sorry I didn't make it clear in my question, I want tmp to be an unique_ptr to A, not just raw pointer.

Comment: Nicol is telling you that that is irrelevant to the problem/question, and he's right.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I am new to this topic, can you help me clarify this little bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to declare a virtual cloning method in the base class and override it for each subclass:

```
class A {
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const = 0;
}
class B : public A {
    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const override {
        return std::unique_ptr<A>(new B(*this));
    }
};
```

**Edit:**

An usage example:

```
void f(const A& original) {
    std::unique_ptr<A> copy = original.clone();
    // Here, copy points to an instance of class B.
}
```

Comment: Must the clone method be const? If yes,  is `const std::unique_ptr<A> tmp = b.clone()` the right way to use this method? @André Sassi

Comment: @ascetic652, it doesn't *must* be `const`, but it makes sense that cloning an object doesn't modify the original one, doesn't it? The return type is still a non-const `unique_ptr` to a non-const `A` (since it returns the cloned one, not the original), so there is no additional requirement for using `clone`.

Comment: Is it also OK to use `return std::make_unique<A>(*this)`? @André Sassi

Comment: @ascetic652, no, because `make_unique<A>` calls the constructor of `A`, not `B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in this case, I don't have to manage the memory of the cloned object myself, the `unique_ptr` will take care of it automatically, is it correct? @André Sassi

Comment: @ascetic652 Yes, that is the main advantage of using smart pointers.